# WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [DataSource] with qualifiers

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss, cdi

I have the following that is causing the subjected error message in APP-A

```
@Inject @CtcDB
private DataSource ds;
```

I'm using an identical pattern with APP-B which does not complain of this error.
When I hover over `ds` in Eclipse while holding down the ctrl key, I get the following context menu for APP-B

```
Open @Inject Bean Resource.ds
Open Declaration
Open Declared Type
```

but in the APP-A with the dependency error I only get

```
Open Declaration
Open Declared Type
```

// The Resources class is basically the same b/n both apps except the qualifier is @CommitmentDB for APP-B

```
public class Resources {
  @Produces
  @Resource(mappedName="java:jboss/datasources/myjndids")
  @CtcDB
  private DataSource ds;
```

// And my annotation

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE })
public @interface CtcDB{

}
```

I know CDI is active (I have a beans.xml in WEB-INF) because I have a POM dependency which contains some injectable beans. When hovering with the ctr key for those injections I get the expected context menu (in both apps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out myself.  In the Resources class I had the wrong import for DataSource

```
import javax.activation.DataSource; \\instead of
import javax.sql.DataSource;

I must have clicked on the wrong Eclipse Quickfix and imported the wrong package.
```